# How do I detect and remove "\n" from given string in action script?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code,

```
public static function clearDelimeters(formattedString:String):String
{
    return formattedString.split("\n").join("").split("\t").join("");
}
```

The spaces i.e. "\t" are removed but the newline "\n" are not removed from the formattedString.

I even tried

```
public static function clearDelimeters(formattedString:String):String
{
    var formattedStringChar:String = "";
    var originalString:String = "";
    var j:int = 0;
    while((formattedStringChar = formattedString.charAt(j)) != "")
    {
        if(formattedStringChar == "\t" || formattedStringChar == "\n")
        {
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            originalString = originalString + formattedString;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return originalString;
}
```

This also didn't work.
Expected help is the reason why newline delimeters are not removed and some way to remove the newline.
Thank you in anticipation

Comment: try `formattedString.condenseWhite = true;`

Comment: return formattedString.split("\n").join("").split("\t").join("").split("\r").join();      Works Fine... Thank you Cay

Comment: @mgraph: I am currently using flex 4.0 in which String doesn't have the attribute condenseWhite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few cases that the line-end marking may be: CRLF, CR, LF, LFCR. Possibly your string contains CRLF for line endings instead of only LF (\n). And so, with all the LFs removed, some text editors will still treat CRs as line-end characters.

Try this instead:

```
//this function requires AS3
public static function clearDelimeters(formattedString:String):String {     
  return formattedString.replace(/[\u000d\u000a\u0008\u0020]+/g,""); 
}
```

Note that \t is for tab, it's not space. Or if you're working with HTML, <br> and <br/> are used to make line breaks in HTML but they are not line-end characters.

Comment: Paul, the above code only replace only one delimeter at a time. so it has to be called iteratively till all the delimeters gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The regexp answer is correct but I always like the more readable version of it (don't know how it does with performance though)

```
result = string.split("\n\r").join("");
```

or do the \n and \r split separate. The \n\r is a common standard for all operating systems. Check wikipedia to check why those are joined together((CR+LF, '\r\n', 0x0D0A)).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't a

```
<br>
```

or

```
</br>?
```

or

```
/r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this. it works for me!!! Wink-;^D
function removeNewLinesFrom(This){
nl='' + newline;
removed=''
for(i=0;i<=(This.length-1);i++){
if(This.charAt(i)!=nl){removed+=This.charAt(i)}
}
return(removed)
}
// Simplify the name of the function
rnlf=removeNewLinesFrom
// Wright a example
example='hello '+newline+'world'
// prompt the example
trace('prompt='+rnlf(example))
```